# undefined amount of data in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, size, undefined, multidimensional-array

I have a form, where a user inputs alot of different data, among other amount of iterations and amount of asked people. This that my function has to do a multidimensional array with a undefined number of "subarrays".

Basicly, what I want is to make a large array, that has $amount_of_iterations subarrays, which each has $amount_of_asked_people values.

However, I've tried to make this code, which doesnt work:

```
$my_multidimensional_array = array();
$x = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount_of_iterations; $i++)
{
    for ($p = 0; $p < $amount_of_asked_people; $p++)
    {
        $x = rand();//actually an other function, but this will do for testing
        $my_multidimensional_array[$i] = array($p => $x);
    }
}

//But when i test it i get an error. Here is my testing code:
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount_of_iterations; $i++)
{
        echo "<h1>Iteration number $i:</h1>";
        for ($p = 0; $p < $amount_of_asked_people; $p++)
        {
            echo "<br />The Random value is: $my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p]";
        }
}
```

(I've modified the real variable names and function for privacy, but this should work for testing.)

When i echo this, i only get this(where as i should get something like "The Random value: 7771"):

Iteration number 0:

```
The Random value: Array[0]
The Random value: Array[1]
```

etc.

Iteration number 1:

```
The Random value: Array[0]
The Random value: Array[1]
```

etc.etc.

Comment: http://codepad.org/hWwuuKj9 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

Every time you iterate over the following line, you're clobbering result of any previous iteration for a given `$i`:

```
$my_multidimensional_array[$i] = array($p => $x);
```

Rewrite it as:

```
if(!isset($my_multidimensional_array[$i])) $my_multidimensional_array[$i] = array();
$my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p] = $x;
```

Additionally, in your test, you're not accessing the array variable correctly in your output string.  Use one of the following methods instead:

```
echo "<br />The Random value is: {$my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p]}";
// or
echo "<br />The Random value is: ".$my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p];
```

Comment: +1, Using correct form of concatenation will result in the value being printed.

Comment: You could just declare the array in the first loop, otherwise good catch on his other problem.

Comment: @HoLyVieR, you're right: far more efficient and elegant to just declare it at the right time instead of constantly checking for it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use array variable in quotes, you need to surround them with `{}` if you want to make sure it's properly parsed.

```
echo "<br />The Random value is: {$my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p]}";
```

Comment: You don't **need** to do this, abetter way would be concatenation `echo "<br />The Random value is:" . $my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p];`

Comment: @RobertPitt Of course contatenation is better, but if you re-read my answer it says `When you use array variable in quotes` which is what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: dude, sorry, I didn't see that error, but now that it is corected I still get a undefined offset error when i echo the values, which makes me guess that it is the insertion that makes the error...

Comment: @GunnarKnudsen see Schwartzie answer for why you get undefined index error.

Comment: Yea use: `$my_multidimensional_array[$i][$p] = $x;` instead of array($p => $x)